# spring security java config - multiple authentication manager

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm working on a java spring mvc application. Here is a part of my `SecurityConfig` class for set `AuthenticationManager`:

```
...
@Autowired
private SecurityDAO securityDAO;
...
@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder registry) throws Exception {
    registry.userDetailsService(securityDAO).passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
}
```

The `SecurityDAO` is a class that implements `UserDetailsService` interface.

Now, **I need to have two different implementation of `UserDetailsService` interface.** One for `admin` users with url `/admin/login` and one for `customer` with url `/customer/login`.

I found some samples that implements multiple authentication manager with spring, but all of them use **XML config** and I can't find an example with **java config**.

[Here is a sample of xml config.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18054433/1531130) In fact, I want to convert this config into java config.

Answer (score 0):

Extend AbstractAutowiringFactoryBean and add your implementation in that class.

It has two methods,doCreateInstance() to know whose object needs to be instantiated and getObjectType()  to know which interface implementation is this.

For example

```
@Configuration
public class CLass extends AbstractAutowiringFactoryBean<Object> {

    public enum Env {
        devloper, production
    }

    Env envType = Env.devloper;

    @Override
    protected Object doCreateInstance() {
        switch (envType) {
            case devloper:

                return new ClassImpl1();
            case production:
                rreturn new ClassImpl2();

        }
        throw new RuntimeException("Unsupported implementation type");
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> getObjectType() {
        return SecurityDAO.class;
    }

}
```