# Two UserDetailsServices in Spring, Java config

Tags: java, spring, configuration

I am trying to configure two `UserDetailsService`s for the authentication of two different user groups and I came across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18040298/two-separate-userdetailsservice-implementations). However, it is using xml configuration, how would I accomplish the same using Java configuration?

As far as I know, the http element is configured by overriding the `configure(HttpSecurity http)` method, but how do I configure multiple http elements?

I do know that in many scenarios, it would be sufficient to have one `UserDetailsManager` which manages two user database tables, but I am curious how the other solution would look like in case I decide for it.

Comment: Do you have two different entry points where different type of users login, or do you have a single entry point but the users authentication data (login/password) are stored in two different stores/tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not see any reason for you to be using 2 UserDetails implementations, as you are saying you need to authenticate two different user groups. Would suggest to look at http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#authorization and think would give you a lot of pointers where you should go from there.
What you are in need is upon authentication in system to know what the logged in user Role is and define it. Two ways are indeed one via xml second is Annotation based in a @Configuration java class with the specifics laid out there. Read up the above link I posted for you and you should be able to see what Spring offers and what you are in need to do actually.

Would take a lot of space First to put it down and Second it is a very broad question you are asking as the post link you are referring to is incorrect in the way it handles Spring Security.